Flink can configure memory for a specific RocksDB state？
In my Flink job, I’m using RocksDB with several keyed states in different operators. Some states only contain small amounts of data, while others need to store large amounts. As I understand, I can use state.backend.rocksdb.writebuffer.size and state.backend.rocksdb.block.cache-size to control memory usage for all states. However, for smaller states, this memory allocation seems wasteful. Is there a way to allocate more memory for larger states to reduce disk I/O wait times?

No, that sort of granular configuration isn't possible.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
